# Localstorage Cannot set property of #<Object> which has only a getter

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I'm making a todo app and when I'm trying to assign an array of todos stored in localStorage to an array called todayTasks, it throws this error.
[image]

here's the code

```js
const savetoStorage = () =>{
    localStorage.setItem('todayTasks',JSON.stringify(todayTasks))
}

const downloadfromStorage = () => {
    const key = localStorage.key('todayTasks')
    const value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
    todayTasks = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove that first line of code in your download function and this will work

```
const downloadfromStorage = () => {
    const value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todayTasks'));
    todayTasks = value;
}
```